Access model coefficients/weights of MLLinearRegressor (CreateML, CoreML)
My code looks something like this
import CreateML

let dataTable: DataFrame = [
            "feature1": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
            "feature2": [3.0, 4.0, 4.5, 3.4, 4.5, 6.2],
            "target": [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0]
]
        

let model = try MLLinearRegressor(trainingData: dataTable, targetColumn: "target")

I would like to access the model's coefficients/weights. Is that possible?
